# Unzip artifacts after upload (store_artifacts)

Tags: python, python-sphinx, circleci

We use Sphinx to build our Python documentation and then store the artifact. GitHub then shows directly a link in the CI to open the `index.html`.

But when building Sphinx doc, thousands of files are created which slows down the upload of the artifact. To reduce upload time, from the [doc](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/artifacts/), I can upload a compressed folder. But then, how to persist the uncompressed folder? This is needed as we have a file `artifact_path` which needs a path to the `index.html`. Or is there another way around this?

```
- store_artifacts:
    path: folder.tar  # untar after?
```

Disclamer: this is for SciPy, I am a core-dev. This would be extremely helpful as it takes around 30% of the build time of this pipeline.

Comment: Maybe start with reading [CircleCI's docs on deployment](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/?section=deployment)? I imagine there is a Bash script that you could write that extracts the archive and that you place on the target server, then fire of a remote command to execute it.

Comment: @StevePiercy which target server are you talking about? The doc is hosted by CircleCI on `persist_to_workspace `. There is nothing more. We have an extra file `artifact_path` with just the path to the index `0/html-scipyorg/index.html`. Link to the config: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml
There is no deploy step for the feature branches.

Comment: Are you not able to execute shell scripts on the CircleCI server? If you can, the same concept for a target server would apply to a local CircleCI server.

Comment: @StevePiercy do you mean: using a deploy stage which connects to the persisted workspace and unpack there? Is this possible and will it stays unpacked afterwards? I will try.

Comment: Is your goal here to have the artifacts be viewable directly in the browser from the CircleCI job page after the upload completes? If so, you won't be able to have them be archived into a single file.

Artifacts end up as individual files on S3, so there's no way to upload an archive and have it decompressed post-upload.

Comment: @Glenjamin that was the goal yes. It's just super convenient to be able to see the html directly on GitHub without having to download all the ressources locally. Then it means that we would either need to host ourself the ressources (not really doable), or resort to not having this nice preview. Because right now it takes almost 10 minutes to upload the artifacts...

Comment: CircleCI released the Dynamic Config features https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/dynamic-config/ which enable tighter controls on when to perform certain jobs under certain conditions. I suggest implementing something like this example https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-cookbook/?section=examples-and-guides#execute-specific-workflows-or-steps-based-on-which-files-are-modified and only build + upload artifacts when your Docs change. This should lessen your build times. So instead of building and uploading docs on every build you can execute them when you need to.

Comment: @punkdata well in our case we would almost always want to render the doc as it's generated based on the code. For something more static this could be a solution though. Because in the end we can also add a skip info in the commit message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CircleCI is using AWS to store files. Hence you cannot uncompress artifacts and serve them directly.

We would need to use another service/server to get the artifact, uncompress and serve the files.